# Python Leaderboard for little game

Tags: python

I'm farly new to python and for a project, I want to add a leaderboard to a small game.

- The user makes a score in the game and then he should be able to input a username.
- The username and the score have to be connected to each other.
- After that I want to save it in a textfile, where it is sorted with the highest score at the top.

Example:

```py
score = 5
username = input()
x = open('leaderboard.txt', "a")
#the next line does not work because there are 2 elements
x.writelines(username, score)
x.close()
```

To finish it of, I want to sort the leaderboard, with the highest score at the top.

At the moment, the leaderboard looks like this:

```
user 1, 2
user 121, 5
user 222, 6
mix, 11
hey, 5
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `x.writelines([username, score])`?..

Comment: @Sayse thank you for solving my first problem! do you now how to sort it when there are 5 user and scores?

Comment: Can you show your leaderboard.txt?

Comment: @ppwater here you go: user 1, 2
user 121, 5
user 222, 6
mix, 11
hey, 5

Comment: could you [edit] that into the question?

Comment: @ppwater did it!

Comment: Ah, okay, but please format your code with backticks ``` next time!

Comment: Just a few ideas: 
You could use a .json file to store the leaderboard. And so you'd use the json module to read to and write from it. 
Regarding sorting, I would read all the already existing scores each time and convert those into a dict with username as key and score as value, add the new score to it, and use the sort method on it, then re-write all of it in your .json.

Comment: I should add that you should try to break down questions like this one into as many parts as you can before posting them here. That could even help you find already existing answers. Of course though, sometimes it can be hard to break down your question, I would even argue that can be the hardest part, but here you seem to have figured out that there are several parts. My two cents ;-)

Comment: @AndreiToroplean thank you for your answer! i'll try that. I'm new to stackoverflow but next time I will do so

Comment: @lippo of course, no problem. Don't hesitate if you have follow up questions. Maybe you can post them on the site (but check that they haven't already been answered), and point us to them here.

Comment: and By the way, try to read the [tour] (you get a badge!) and [ask]

Comment: If you have another question you should raise it as another question, although make sure to do research into solving it yourself first.

Comment: I think the last part of your puzzle is that sorting the leaderboard *file* is a red herring, it doesn't matter how the file is sorted, you will read the file into a list and sort the list before you show it to the user (sorting a list is a 'solved problem' you can find lots of info on here!)

Answer (score 1):

I am also newbie to Python too. Here's how I would go around this problem. If anyone has a better solution please let me know too.

1. For my method to work, there should be a change in the way `leaderboard.txt`. I assume that usernames are **unique**.
   To **read** data from already saved file:

   ```
   def read_file():
       with open('leaderboard.txt', 'r') as board:
           return board.readlines()
   ```

   This return a array. It looks like this:

   ```
   ['swlfnLKWF|828725\n', 'asncfa|283893\n', 'user|122302\n', 'DALSJFO|86383\n']
   ```
2. Sorting the leaderboard. The way each value saved is to connect and separate the scores easily. `username|score`. I use `|` to separate username from scores. I am using Python's own `sorted()` for sorting.

   - **Preprocessing** the data:

     ```
     def array_to_dict(a):
         # Returns a dictionary for sorting
         d = {}
         for i in a:
             d[i[:i.index('|')]] = int(i[i.index('|')+1:].strip('\n'))
         return d
     ```
   - **Sorting**:

     ```
     def sort_players(dic):
         sorted_dict = sorted(dic.values())
         players = list(dic.keys())
         scores = list(dic.values())

         return [str(players[scores.index(player_score)] + "|" + str(player_score)) for     player_score in sorted_dict[::-1]]
     ```

     This will return an **array** of sorted leaderboard like:
     `['swlfnLKWF|828725', 'asncfa|283893', 'user|122302', 'DALSJFO|86383']`
3. Writing to a file. Again writes each line as `username|score\n`.

   - **Writting**:

     ```
     def write_file(a):
         with open('leaderboard.txt', 'w') as board:
         for line in a:
             board.write(line+'\n')
         print('Write Succesful!')
     ```

- If you want to change an `dict` to a `list`:

  ```
  def dict_to_array(d):
      # d is a dict object.
      return [str(str(k) + "|" + str(v) + '\n') for k,v in d.items()]
  ```
- Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/tree/master/sorts)  where you can find all sorting algorithms if you want.